# Tracking Clicks in Emails to 3rd Party Websites

Tags: email, google-analytics

A hopefully simple GA newbie question.

I programmatically (in Java) send emails to my clients and I'm trying to track what links in the email they click.

The links in the emails are to third party websites.

Is there a way to setup the href links so that I can track what uid's are clicking and treat clicking those links as an event?

An example link would be to a piece of legislation:
https://www.cga.ct.gov/asp/cgabillstatus/cgabillstatus.asp?selBillType=Bill&which_year=2017&bill_num=5210

how would I add that link in the email HTML?

Answer (score 0):

That does not work, at least not with additional resources.

Google Analytics tracks links by sending a request to the Google servers before the user is redirected to the link href. In web tracking this is usually done via a javascript event handler that is attached to the link. In e-mail javascript is not really an option, so that does not work.

What is usually done instead is that in your emails you link to your own server; there is a script that collects the data from the link, and only then it redirects to the originally requested url. Most commercial newsletter packages integrate a solution like that, but you can set up something yourself with some basic programming skills and the Google Analytics [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) (which would allow you to send tracking calls from a server-side redirection script).

Answer (score 0):

## Setup the Redirects Tracking Engine

The Redirects Tracking Engine makes it easy to collect event data where traditional tracking methods may not have been possible. This tracking engine utilizes Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics to capture events and is run on the client side. All events can be seen in Google Analytics **(Behavior > Events > Top Events)**.

### Getting Started

#### Installation

Add the latest JQuery and Redirects Tracking Engine scripts to the header of your site.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">// Fetches redirects.txt and stores information in the variable data
$.get('redirects.txt', function(data) {
    // Fetches the parameters of the query string and stores the path in urlParams
    var urlParams = [];
    // Sifts through the string and removes unwanted characters
    (function () {
        var match,
        pl = /\+/g, // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, '')); },
        query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        while (match = search.exec(query))
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
    // Pulls properties from urlParams and stores them in destination array
    var destination = Object.keys(urlParams).map(function(path){return urlParams[path]});
    // Assigns the redirects.txt data to the userData array
    var userData = data.split('\n');
    // Multidimensional array declaration
    var redirects = [];
    // Fetches the total number of objects in the userData array
    var total = userData.length;
    // Counter variable
    var i = 0;
    // Runs through the redirects array to check to see if there is a string match
    while (i < total) {
            // Places userData into the multidimensional redirects array
        redirects[i] = userData[i].split(' => ');
        // Checks for a path match in the redirects array
        if (redirects[i][0] == destination[1]) {
            window.location.href = redirects[i][1];
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
    // Redirects to safe page if no match is found
    window.location.href = 'https://example.com';
});
```

#### Setup Google Tag Manager

Paste this code as high in the `<head>` of the page as possible. Make sure to substitute the filler `GTM-XXXX` with your Google Tag Manager Account ID.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager --><script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||    [];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?    id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Additionally, paste this code immediately after the opening `<body>` tag. Make sure to substitute the filler `GTM-XXXX` with your Google Tag Manager Account ID here as well.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

**NOTE:** For more information about installing the Google Tag Manager snippet, check out their [Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart).

Create Tags/Triggers/Variables

1. **Create a variable** — You will need to first create a User-Defined Variable. Go to the Variables page of your Google Tag Manager and in the User-Defined Variables section create a new variable named `Tracking ID`. Give this variable your Google Analytics Tracking ID in the Value field and **SAVE**.
2. **Create a tag** — You will need to go to the *Tags* page in Google Tag Manager and click the **NEW** button. Fill in the fields and click **SAVE** when finished.
3. **Create a trigger** — Finally, you will need to create a trigger. Go to the *Triggers* page in Google Tag Manager. Once there click on the **NEW** button and fill in the fields and click **SAVE** when finished.

After these configurations have been setup in Google Tag Manager you are ready to add your redirects to the `redirects.txt` file.

#### Redirects

To add a redirect open the `redirects.txt` file. The text `linkedin` is telling the engine what path it needs to look for in the URL. Immediately following is the separator `=>` which shows the engine where the assigned path should direct the user. New redirects can be added on a new line and there are no limits to the number of redirects that can be added to this file.

```
// Example Redirect
linkedin => https://example.com
```

#### Failsafe

In the off-chance that one of the redirects is not working it is good to have a page that the user can be directed to. You can add in your failsafe page by modifying the `window.location.href` location that comes immediately after the loop.

```
// Redirects to safe page if no match is found
window.location.href = 'https://example.com';
```

### Browser Support

*Supported Browsers* : Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge, IE7+.

The source code as well as an example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/peterburdette/Redirects-Tracking-Engine).